# How do I avoid code duplication in my case?

Tags: java, optimization, design-patterns, code-duplication

I am currently working on code that converts one data model to another. More precisely, it is a Hafas model, but it is not very important. The problem is that I have to support multiple versions of this model. I currently have a converter for version 1.23 and version 1.29. Thousands of lines of code, about 50 methods that are 97% identical.

So I get XML with the data that I first need to deserialize to the POJO classes I constructed and then convert them with my algorithms.

The problem is that these versions use different packages of my POJO classes that have 99% same names.

Here is one example:
Converter for 1.23 version:

```
public void convertHafasLegsInsideCustomTrip(TripStructure myTrip, LegList hafasLegs) {
    for (Leg hafasLeg :
            hafasLegs.getLeg()
    ) {
        // We have to convert each Hafas Leg to Trias TripLegStructure
        TripLegStructure myTripLeg= convertToTriasTripLeg(hafasLeg);

        if (myTripLeg!= null)
            myTrip.getTripLeg().add(myTripLeg);
        else
            throw new NullPointerException("ERROR: HAFAS TripResult conversion ended up with NULL object");
    }
}
```

Converter for V1.29:

```
public void convertHafasLegsInsideCustomTrip(TripStructure myTrip, LegList hafasLegs) {
    for (Leg hafasLeg :
            hafasLegs.getLeg()
    ) {
        // We have to convert each Hafas Leg to Trias TripLegStructure
        TripLegStructure myTripLeg= convertToTriasTripLeg(hafasLeg);

        if (myTripLeg!= null)
            myTrip.getTripLeg().add(myTripLeg);
        else
            throw new NullPointerException("ERROR: HAFAS TripResult conversion ended up with NULL object");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `LegList` and `Leg` inside packages are different. So in the first case, they are imported from the generated POJO classes for version 1.23 and in the second example from the POJO classes for version 1.29.

The algorithm that converts is almost identical and I have many other methods that are 100% identical, only a few of them are different because some classes have different names in these two packages.

My next problem is that I may later implement a converter for another version that will also have similar features and I don't want to duplicate the code for each of them.

Comment: Well, you are probably out of luck, unless they share some common interface that is stable across versions you'd have to resort to reflection.

Comment: A common interface would definitely help here and would probably be the best solution. In cases where you need version specific attributes or method you'd then need to cast and use version specific methods. If you can't provide a common interface you might be able to use some sort of decorator that implements it but depending on the number of methods this might be a lot of work.

Comment: @Hulk, just some of them, not all. That is why I thought that maybe with some modified design pattern there is a possible solution for my problem.

Comment: @Thomas, I already tried a Decorator solution but I saw that there are thousands of methods that I have to implement and it doesn't make sense to write so much for just 2 versions of the converter.

Comment: @ChuckNuris well then, I guess Reflection may be worth trying. It certainly has disadvantages (detection of problems at runtime rather than compile time, performance) but it allows you to look up the methods by name.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have one set of generated POJO classes for the 1.23 XML in one package, and a different set, generated for the 1.29 XML in a different package, although these two versions share a lot of common aspects. The problem is caused by the code generator not matching your use case of XML schema evolution. Either, find a better code generator (if one exists at all), or e.g. work with the XML DOM tree directly.